# Azure Function deployment not using VS Code extension

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I am trying to deploy Azure Function performing a simple calculation. It is deployed successfully, because I can see *Your Functions 4.0 app is up and running*. My logic ([inspired by this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-python)) is set up as follows.

```
import azure.functions as func
app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
@app.route(route="addition")
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> str:
    a = req.params.get("a")
    b = req.params.get("b")
    return "{}".format(int(a) * int(b))
```

When I navigate to `/api/addition?a=2&b=3` I don't see the expected result. Instead I get 404 Not Found.

I have tried deploying using [VS Code Azure Function extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python?pivots=python-mode-decorators). It was successful and I could confirm the expected result on the screen. However I want to do it without VS Code. What am I missing? Googling it is challenging because everyone asks how to **do it in** VS Code.

The buildpipe compiles roughly like so.

```
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: $(pythonVersion)
    disableDownloadFromRegistry: true
    addToPath: true
    architecture: 'x64'
  displayName: 'Use python $(pythonVersion)'
- script: |
    python -m venv antenv
    source antenv/bin/activate
    pip install -r requirements.txt
  workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
  displayName: 'Install requirements'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(projectRoot)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- publish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
  artifact: drop
```

Then, it deploys like this.

```
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: $(pythonVersion)
    disableDownloadFromRegistry: true
    addToPath: true
    architecture: 'x64'
    displayName: 'Use python $(pythonVersion)'
          
- task: AzureFunctionApp@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
    appType: 'functionAppLinux'
    appName: 'func-calculationtest'
    package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    runtimeStack: 'PYTHON|3.10'
    deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

Comment: Do you build and deploy your function app in one yaml file? You can download the pipeline artifact "drop" from the pipeline and deploy it on your local machine via [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#cli) and check whether it works as expected. If it works, the issue may be related to your pipeline deployment. If it doesn't work, it may be related to your build or your project.

Comment: Downloaded stuff works locally. How should I proceed troubleshooting @ZiyangLiu-MSFT?

Comment: You can run the same command, which works locally, in the pipeline to deploy your function app instead of using "AzureFunctionApp" task. Then check whether it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created one Azure Functions PythonV2 Http Trigger with your code that does simple addition, Pushed the code to Azure Repository and Deployed it to Function app via Azure DevOps like below:-

***Select below option from the DevOps yaml template and deploy your Function app:-***

[image]

**Yaml code:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- master

variables:
  
  azureSubscription: 'correct-serviceconnection'

  
  functionAppName: 'siliconfunc58'

  
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.6'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.10 # Functions V2 supports Python 3.6 as of today

    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have tried your suggestion @SiddheshDesai. It does work. However the [url](https://func-calculationtest.azurewebsites.net/api/addition?a=2&b=9) does not work, giving me 404 Not Found.

Comment: Did you try it via code + test panel like I have done?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and my response code is also 200 OK with expected result. However the [url](https://func-calculationtest.azurewebsites.net/api/addition?a=2&b=9) is not working I want to see the response in the browser.